# prevent trap from altering underscore variable $_

Tags: bash, shell, parameter, trap, variable

I have the following code in my bashrc to get the execution time of the last command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862762

```
function timer_start {
  timer=${timer:-$SECONDS}
}

function timer_stop {
  timer_show=$(($SECONDS - $timer))
  unset timer
}

trap 'timer_start' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND=timer_stop

PS1='[last: ${timer_show}s][\w]$ '
```

but when I run `echo $_` it shows "timer_start" instead of the last commands parameter.

How can I change this to preserve the `$_` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
trap '__=$_; timer_start; : "$__"' DEBUG
```